# Single codebase but different style templates (scss) per customer

Tags: git

I am using `git` for my code, Now what I need to do is to manage single codebase for all the customers but each customer have different sytle templates.

I have one master bracnh at the moment. The business logic will also be evolved with the passage of time.

So I need to use the latest code for all the customers but induvidual styles for each customer

What are the possibilities to solve such problem

Comment: You can create separate branch for all the customers

Comment: I would say "don't do this". Consider instead putting the styles in a separate repo?

Comment: Although you _could_ solve this problem using git I wouldn't advise it. This is an application configuration problem, not a source control management problem.